# Proving that X with partial order forms a topology with lower sets.

Tags: general-topology

Let $\leq$ be a partial order on $X$. Then $(X, \tau)$ where  $\tau = \{\, U \subseteq X :  \forall x,y\in X\ \ (x\in U\ \land\ y\le x)\ \rightarrow\ y \in U\,\}$ forms a topological space.

Of course, $\emptyset \in \tau$ and $X \in \tau$ comes naturally.

Finite intersection is also easy - if $T_1$ and $T_2 \in \tau$ then there are $U_1, U_2 \subset X$ such that if $x \in U_1$ and $y \leq x$ then $y \in U_2$ and if $x \in U_2$ and $y \leq x$ then $y \in U_2$.

Then taking arbitrary $x \in T_1 $ and $x \in T_2$:

$$
\left(x \in T_1 \wedge x \in T_2\right) \implies
$$

$$
\left(\left( x \in U_1 \wedge y \leq x  \implies y \in U_1 \right) \wedge
\left( x \in  U_2 \wedge y \leq x  \implies y \in U_2 \right) \right) \implies
$$

$$
\left( x \in  U_1 \wedge x \in U_2 \wedge y \leq x  \implies y \in U_1 \wedge y \in U_2 \right) \implies
$$

$$
\left( x \in  U_1 \cap U_2 \wedge y \leq x  \implies y \in U_1 \cap U_2 \right) \in \tau
$$

How can I prove that uncountable union of sets from $\tau$ is also in $\tau$?

Comment: The $U_i$ is just $T_i$, aren't they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very easy: if $x\in\bigcup_iU_i$ with arbitrary index set, and $y\le x$, then $x\in U_i$ for some $i$, and $y\in U_i$ follows since $U_i\in\tau$, hence $y\in\bigcup_i U_i$.